# Displaying alerts on different rows (vertically)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In one part of my program I append some `alerts` to `body-content`. I'd like them to be vertically positioned, each on a different row.

[image: alert]

I can get this by adding a `<div class="row"></div>` before each `alert`. My template looks like this:

```
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable pull-left" style="width:300px;">
.......
</div>
```

If I remove the `<div class="row"></div>` element, alert's will be stacked horizontally:

[image: alert]

I'd like to achieve the desired effect without adding any other element, because they'll not be cleaned after dismissing the `alert`.

Comment: i have posted code have a look and it may help you for the same

Comment: i hope my code was useful to you if u have any issues with it let me know :)

Comment: Thanks for your help Iqbal, maybe I got something wrong but Alex's code is the only one that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Bootstrap Alert Message</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .alert{
        clear: left;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="alert alert-warning pull-left" style="width:300px;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> A simple alert message.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning pull-left" style="width:300px;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> A simple alert message.
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-warning pull-left" style="width:300px;">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
        <strong>Warning!</strong> A simple alert message.
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Taken help from these pages:

http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-alerts.php
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/css-alignment.php

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Pull-left` from the alert class. Please see the below code.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable pull-left" style="width:300px;">
    .......
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It works, but I want them to be on the other side of the page (my page is right aliged).

Comment: Try to include the alert on the `clear-fix` class in boostrap. I have updated the code. also you can include a div without `clear-fix` class.

Comment: Thanks Fazil, adding a `clear-fix` didn't solve the problem, and they're still horizontally aligned. However it has the issue that I have mentioned at the question, dismissing `alert` doesn't remove that element, the container `div`.

Answer (score 1):

here is the code have a look and it may help you to fix the problem

```css
#infoBox{
  display : flex;
  float : right;
}

#infoBox div{
  margin : 5px;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="infoBox">

  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> A simple alert message.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> A simple alert message.
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> A simple alert message.
  </div>

</div>
```